# How to convert jenkins build timstamp to normal date format in shell script

Tags: shell, date, jenkins

i need to convert jenkins build timestamp to a proper date format using a shell script or using a UNIX one liner.
I tried a couple of things, but they seem to give the wrong date.
Here is what i tried so far
jenkins timestamp is `1516684619524` which translates to current date `Jan 22, 2018 11:16:59 PM`

since jenkins timestamp is in miliseconds, so i divided the timestamp by 1000 and then ran

```
>>date -d @151668461
Tue Oct 22 05:07:41 CDT 1974
```

the date is correct but the time is wrong

also i tried

```
>>date -d @151668461 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
1974-10-22 05:07:41
```

which is also not correct

can someone help me with the correct answer to this

Answer (score 2):

You have divided by 10000 instead of 1000. Rest is fine.

date -d @1516684619 +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: okay..but i want the format in DD:MM:YYYY:Hour:minute:second, date -d @1516684619524 does not give that

Comment: prex, you can use  this format to get required format. **date -d @1516684619 +'%d:%m:%Y:%H:%M:%S'**